# Storing and retrieving files in Blockly Web

Tags: blockly

I want to use Blockly to do some calculations, and then generate text files (as opposed to exporting code to JavaScript, Python, PHP, etc.)

I can’t see an obvious way to create my own blocks to do this in Blockly, so using AppInventor (Version: nb168), I got storing and retrieving files to work, in a crude test app on my Android tablet.
In AppInventor/Designer mode, clicking Storage/File creates a “Non-visible component for storing and retrieving files. Use this component to write or read files on your device.”
Then, in AppInventor/Blocks mode, clicking the “File1” icon gives access to 7 “file type blocks”, e.g. AppendToFile, Delete, ReadFrom, SaveFile, etc.

Is it possible to create similar “file type blocks” to use in Blockly Web?

I have limited programming knowledge, so would appreciate simple answers, please.
Thanks, Pete.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew N Marshall from Google/Blockly has told me this:

"This is absolutely possible  ...as long as you willing to work within the browser's security restrictions. The resulting files will be need to be manually "downloaded" one at a time, rather than written directly to the user's file system.

... I would start understanding what JavaScript functions are available to you. Attempt to construct a string and save it via a download dialog...

That means the "file" contents are really just a string in memory, a JavaScript variable.  We have lots of "Text" blocks that can do a variety of operations on strings. If those are enough, you'll only need one new block to identify the string variable and initiate the download process.

Otherwise, you'll need to think about what blocks you want, and how they operate. They may operate on a specific variable in the JavaScript VM, not necessary exposed as a variable to Blockly.

Either way, you'll need to learn how to create a block and a Blockly app. We have a code lab that will walk you through all the steps. You'll learn how each block generates a string of code, and in your case, that code will be related to the download code I mentioned earlier."

So I'll press on - I just wanted to be sure my goal is actually achievable before I started. 
Thanks, Pete.

Comment: I approve of this post.